# Lock cells and only have users with specific email address update these cells in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to set permissions to update cells based on the email address column on the spreadsheet. For example, I have a cell "B2" that needs to be locked down and should only be unlocked for modification for the user accessing the sheet with email address "123@abc.com", which is present as a row value on the same sheet. The email address would be the same email address the user uses to view the sheet. Image shown below. Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [protection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection).

Here is some code that will do just this for you:

This will go down the `email` column and add a protected range to the cell to the immediate right of the email address.

```js
function ProtectRanges(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var columns = GetColumns(values, range.getNumColumns(), 0); //Get the column headers

  for(var  i = 1; i < values.length; i++){
    var email = values[i][columns.columns['email'].index]; //Get the email address from the 'email' columns
    if(email !== ''){
      var rangeToProtect = ss.getRange(i+1, columns.columns['owner'].index + 1, 1, 1); //Get the range to protect, one cell over
      rangeToProtect.protect().addEditor(email).setDescription("Only " + email + " has edit rights"); //Protect the range and add a description      
    }
  }
}

//Gets a columns object for the sheet for easy indexing
function GetColumns(valuesRange, columnCount, rowIndex)
{
  var columns = {
    columns: {},
    length: 0
  }

  Logger.log("Populating columns...");
  for(var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
  {
    if(valuesRange[0][i] !== ''){
      columns.columns[valuesRange[0][i]] = {index: i ,value: valuesRange[0][i]};
      columns.length++;      
    }
  }  
  return columns;
}
```